# Аналог функционала C# в Python

Tags: python, процесс

На просторах YouTube наткнулся на видео, в котором парень, используя язык C#, считывает напрямую значение ячейки памяти некоторого процесса, зная название процесса и адрес самой ячейки (в данном примере это процесс игры Minecraft и программист считывает уровень здоровья главного героя игры). Предоставляет ли мне Python подобную функциональность: считывание данных из произвольного процесса?

Спасибо
[image: Код]

Comment: Я скажу точно, что вам эту возможность предоставит - Java. И код в вопрос лучше вставлять текстом.

Comment: [python read memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1794579/5752652)

Comment: @aepot и давно java стала подмножеством python или C#?

Comment: @Kers я к тому что майнкрафт - это JVM приложение.